# How can I split my C code in different files

Tags: c, visual-c++

I'm tying to split my C code in multiple files, since it has more than 3,000 lines now, and I want to organize my code. Here is a simplified version of my code in a single file:

lib.c

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define MAIN_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define MAIN_EXPORT_API
#endif

typedef struct Vertex Vertex;
typedef struct Element Element;
typedef struct Grid Grid;

struct Vertex {
    int index;
    Element *element;
};
struct Element {
    int index;
    Vertex vertex;
};
struct Grid {
    Vertex *vertex;
    Element *element;
};

MAIN_EXPORT_API Vertex Vertex_init (int index) {
    Vertex vertex;
    vertex.index = index;
    return vertex;
}
MAIN_EXPORT_API Element Element_init (int index, Vertex *vertexPtr) {
    Element element;
    element.index = index;
    vertexPtr->element = &element;
    return element;
}
MAIN_EXPORT_API Grid Grid_init () {
    Grid grid;
    Vertex vertex = Vertex_init(0);
    Element element = Element_init(0, &vertex);
    grid.vertex = &vertex;
    grid.element = &element;
    return grid;
}
```

Then I tried to start splitting it in the following way:

new_lib.h

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
#  if defined(LIB_EXPORTS)
#    define LIB_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#    define LIB_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#  endif
#else
#  define LIB_EXPORT_API
#endif

typedef struct Vertex Vertex;
typedef struct Element Element;
typedef struct Grid Grid;

struct Vertex {
    int handle;
    Element *element;
};
struct Element {
    int handle;
    Vertex vertex;
};
struct Grid {
    Vertex *vertex;
    Element *element;
};
```

new_lib.c

```
#define LIB_EXPORTS
#include "new_lib.h"

Element Element_init (int handle, Vertex *vertexPtr) {
    Element element;
    element.handle = handle;
    vertexPtr->element = &element;
    return element;
}
Grid Grid_init () {
    Grid grid;
    Vertex vertex = Vertex_init(0);
    Element element = Element_init(0, &vertex);
    grid.vertex = &vertex;
    grid.element = &element;
    return grid;
}
```

vertex.h

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
#  if defined(VERTEX_EXPORTS)
#    define VERTEX_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#    define VERTEX_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#  endif
#else
#  define VERTEX_EXPORT_API
#endif

#include "lib.h"

VERTEX_EXPORT_API Vertex Vertex_init (int handle);
```

vertex.c

```
#define VERTEX_EXPORTS
#include "vertex.h"

Vertex Vertex_init (int handle) {
    Vertex vertex;
    vertex.handle = handle;
    return vertex;
}
```

And when I compile it I get:

```sh
C:\>
C:\>cl /nologo /DDLL vertex.c /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:vertex.dll
vertex.c
   Creating vertex.lib library and vertex.exp object 

C:\>cl /nologo /DDLL new_lib.c /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:new_lib.dll vertex.lib
new_lib.c
new_lib.c(12): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'int' to 'Vertex'

C:\>
C:\>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can split it as you like.:)

Comment: The problem is that `new_lib.c` doesn't have the declaration of `Vertex_init` because you haven included the `vertex.h` header file.

Comment: There are other much more serious problems though, like you storing and in essence returning pointers to local variables. Once the `Grid_init` function returns, all local variables like `vertex` and `element` goes out of scope and their life-time ends. Any pointer to them will become invalid.

Comment: This version I've shown is a shorter version of my program. There I'm using malloc whenever I need to use pointers, and at the end of the program I loop over all these pointers and free them. But thank you.

Comment: @GustavoExel: The problem is you've shortened it wrong. The error is with your `initializing` method, but your question here doesn't _have_ an `initializing` method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When we split code in c language one of the most important things to notice is to compilation. When code is getting to different files each of the files needs to be compiled separately, this will help in any case of changes to the code since only the changed file would have to be recompiled.
The main way to do so is:
first create a makefile that includes compiling for each file there is an example for a makefile as such:

a makefile example

```
myprog: f1.o f2.o f3.o
        gcc -g -Wall -ansi -pedantic  f1.o f2.o f3.o -o myprog -lm      
f1.o:f1.c data.h
        gcc -c -Wall -ansi -pedantic  f1.c -o f1.o -lm
f2.o:f2.c data.h
        gcc -c -Wall -ansi -pedantic  f2.c -o f2.o -lm
f3.o:f3.c data.h
        gcc -c -Wall -ansi -pedantic  f3.c -o f3.o -lm
```

In this makefile example we can see both how to include each of the files and how include their .h file individually if needed.

Comment: Could you, please, use proper punctuation as well as capital letters to start each sentence? English is not the mother tongue for many users of StackOverflow, skipping important parts of English writing makes the text hard to comprehend for them.

Comment: I don't think makefiles are the norm with Visual C++, is it?

Comment: it is not my respond was for c language only. sorry